# git push hangs after entering password

Tags: git, ssl, github, gitlab

I'm working for a university and they have a gitlab page that we use to push material to students.  I used to be able to push to this repo just fine, but now after typing `git push origin master` and entering my name and password, it hangs and I'm forced to Ctr-C to exit.

I'm using git for windows 10 on a brand new machine.

I can pull from this repo just fine and I've tried reinstalling git and recloning the repo.  If I run with GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 I get:

```
Couldn't find host (REDACTED) in the _netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying (HOST IP)...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to (REDACTED) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / (REDACTED)
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=(REDACTED)
*  start date: Jan  9 04:42:49 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr  9 04:42:49 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "(REDACTED)" matched cert's REDACTED
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle REDACTED)
> GET (REDACTED).git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/2
Host: (REDACTED)
User-Agent: git/2.20.1.windows.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Pragma: no-cache

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 401
< server: nginx
< date: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 01:00:53 GMT
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 26
< cache-control: no-cache
< www-authenticate: Basic realm="GitLab"
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-request-id: REDACTED
< x-runtime: REDACTED
< x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
<
* Connection #0 to host (REDACTED) left intact
```

Then it prompts for user name and password, I enter them and

```
 Found bundle for host (REDACTED): REDACTED [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (REDACTED)
* Connected to (REDACTED) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user (REDACTED)
* Using Stream ID: 3 (easy handle REDACTED )
> GET (REDACTED).git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/2
Host: (REDACTED)
Authorization: Basic (REDACTED)
User-Agent: git/2.20.1.windows.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/2 200
< server: nginx
< date: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 01:05:58 GMT
< content-type: application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement
< content-length: 195
< cache-control: no-cache
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
<
* Connection #0 to host (REDACTED) left intact
```

This is where it hangs.  The git processes are still running when I look at task manager.

`$ git status` returns what you would expect

`$ git pull` returns `Already up to date`

`$ git remote -v` returns:

```
origin  (REDACTED).git (fetch)
origin  (REDACTED).git (push)
```

Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: You may want to change your password and/or make sure no other services are using it, since you've just copy/pasted credentials pair in your question.

Comment: I thought I replaced them all with REDACTED, but I replaced a few more strings now in case they are important.

Comment: Plain text base64 credentials were in the log and history of edits is visible, so still don't forget to change your password.

Comment: Do you have 2FA active? (2 factor Authentication)

Comment: FYI, I had a similar problem and it turned out my stty crnl was messed up. I changed the remote to not include my user-id and saw immediately the ^M when I responded with the User request.